# convert $resource to $http in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I would like convert $resource to $http, How to do it

```
TodoApp.factory('Todo', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/todo/:id', { id: '@id' }, { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});
```

Comment: `$resource` defines many routes automatically for you, so I think you would have to define at least six methods for `$http` for it to be similar.

Comment: Look at your network tab, identify all the request properties and mimic them with `$http`

Comment: @tymeJV how to mimic them please

Comment: What would you like to gain from this? Does $resource have some limitation that blocks you?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by convert? What part of the `$http` docs don't you understand?

Comment: I am newbie in angularjs and trying to understand the logic behind it. I am just wondering if it is doable convert it from each other, that it. Sorry for causing so much confusion.

Comment: Have a look at restangular which is built on top of $http and serves the goal as $resource